# Java api for pdf

Tags: java, pdf

Which APIs in java help in extracting table metadata from a pdf, and presenting that table in a web page?
The result should be that when the source of page is viewed it will show the html code of that table.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean here and I don't. You need a PDF Java Library?

Answer (score 2):

Itext is usefull in this context

http://itextpdf.com/

Answer (score 2):

I assume that, you need a PDF library for Java.
[PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is one of the popular libraries created to PDF manipulation and I think it is worth to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

try The [Metadata Extract Tool](http://meta-extractor.sourceforge.net/) which extracts metadata from specific file types including PDF. Then you can parse the xml output with any Java XML parser. Once you're able to parse it, elements can be easily laid down in your view page.